# affected always shows me all of my projects

Tags: nrwl-nx, nx-affected

My affected call always shows me all libraries.

`nx show projects --affected`

If i run this on a clean develop, this still shows me all of my projects.

Now i branch off of it and make changes to one tiny library, definetly not used by all other libraries and run the command again.

Again, it shows me all of my libraries.

I tried it with  `--base="develop" --head="HEAD"` and `--base="develop"` but it all gives the same result.

What might i be doing wrong?

Comment: having the same problem, did you manage to find a solution for this?